# Replace characters (unique then wildcard value) in a string with other characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, append, wildcard

I have an NSString, let's say "H,L,K,P" how can I detect a specific character than then a wild-car character... for example, checking for ",*" would return ",L" ",K" and ",P" because they all have the specific "," and then they all have a character after them. Then I want to replace that string with itself plus a "period" appended to it.

So "H,L,K,P" would become "H,L.,K.,P."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression. The search pattern would be:

```
,(.)
```

the replacement pattern would be:

```
,$1.
```

Sample code:

```
NSString *string = @"H,L,K,P";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@",(.)"
                                    options:0
                                    error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                    options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                    withTemplate:@",$1."];
```

Comment: I tried using this by replacing @"\u200b" with @"<b>" and it didn't work... I've never used REGEX before so I have no clue what any of this code means but I'm assuming the problem is that your code was made to add a period which has a length of 1 and I'm trying to add the string @"<b>" which has a length of 3? What's the fix?

Comment: What? Your question specifically states you want to add a period. Now you are saying you want to add `<b>`. Which is it?

Comment: I was just giving an example, I have many things I need to be adding at different parts in my code, anyways I did some research and my problem is that with "regex" the period means any character... so when I went to change your example code from periods to "<b>" I accidentally glitched the code haha! Fixed it now, thanks! It would be just my luck to use a period for my example question in question on how to get a wild-card character.. when a period is a wild-card character in RegEx. Haha! Thanks, God bless!

Comment: The period means "any character" in the search pattern. In the replacement pattern is simply means the "period" character.