# RegEx - Detect specific strings before anything that isn't those strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

If I have some specific strings like "∆" "¢" "∑" and "£" and I want to detect anywhere those characters are in a string and that have a character following them that isn't one of those characters and then add a new character after them that relates to those original characters how would I do that..

Example... Find Delta (∆), then a normal character and replace it with "Delta1" then that normal character, then "Delta2"...

so the string: "Hello H∆ow are you?" 
would become: "**Hello H***Delta1***o***Delta2***w are you?**"

Or if I wanted to do multiple ones at once...

For example Replacing ∆ with "Delta1"*"Delta2" AND ∑ with "Sigma1"*"Sigma2"

So: "**HE**∆∑∆∆**LLO**"
Becomes: **He***Delta1**Sigma1**Delta1**Delta1***L***Delta2**Sigma2**Delta2**Delta2***LO**

So basically I have a set of characters... I want to search for where they are up until the first character that comes after them that is NOT in my set of characters... ("43∆∆∆52" searched would return "∆∆∆5" because 5 is not in my set of characters but delta is) then I want to replace all of the characters with another set of characters ("∆" becomes "Delta1") and then at the end of this searched string I add the next set of characters corresponding to the characters that were replaced (in this case "Delta2") so the whole string "∆∆∆5" becomes "*Delta1Delta1Delta1***5***Delta2Delta2Delta2*"

Comment: This seems to be a repost of your problem at [Replace characters (unique then wildcard value) in a string with other characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800240/); it would be preferable that you not accept an answer there which didn't resolve your question, and edit instead to clarify.

Comment: This is an unrelated question for a problem I encountered later on. This is also a RegEx specific question where as my first question was not. Thankyou though.